# My-Weather-Indicator Inaccurate, Not Able To Select Wunder Ground In Options

Tags: weather, my-weather-indicator

I'm using My-Weather-Indicator, but it is never accurate! The Wunderground option is disabled and I can't select it! How do I enable it? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

[image: here's what that menu looks like. Note the Wunderground.com box is disabled]

And what does "Activate" mean?

Comment: And yes. My background is 2 really cute cats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an API key:

Wunderground: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/
World Weather Online: http://www.worldweatheronline.com/register.aspx

Then paste in your key and activate.

Comment: I click the activate button, then nothing happened!

Comment: Presumably you registered with Wunderground, got an API key and pasted it into the indicator dialog BEFORE clicking activate?  If so, then check for [known bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator) and if there are none, log one yourself at the same link.

Comment: OH WAIT! LOL I put in the web address. Stupid me. THX

Comment: Thank you! For those wondering, I requested a free "developer" license (I am a paying wunderground subscriber), and encountered no problem saying that I "my" app was called "My Weather Indictator", and used https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator as the app's website address. They gave me a key immediately and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"we [Wunderground] will no longer provide free weather API keys as part of our program. If you have been directed to download our Weather Underground free API key by a third party provider, please contact your vendor for resolution."
https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/